# Getting a "NoReverseMatch" error in python code

Tags: python, error-handling

Getting this error in my python code when attempting to delete a created topic.
[Here are the url, views, and template snippets.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFU4k.png)

```
path('delete_topic/<int:topic_id>/', views.delete_topic, name='delete_topic')
```

```
def delete_topic(request, topic_id):
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        topic.delete()`enter code here`
        return redirect('online_diaries:topics', topic_id=topic.id)
                
    context = {'topic': topic}   
    return render(request, 'online_diaries/delete_topic.html', context)
```

```
{% extends "online_diaries/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

  <p>Are you sure to delete the topic <b><u>{{ topic }}?</b></u></p>
  <form method="POST" action = "{% url 'online_diaries:delete_topic' topic.id %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      
      <a href="{% url 'online_diaries:topics' %}" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">cancel</a>
      
      <input type = "submit" name = "Confirm" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">  
  </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Please provide a full traceback.

Comment: Check picture link on question. Thanks

Comment: I don't think so. That URL is used to redirect back to the list of topics in the case I click **cancel** instead of ***delete.***